# to store a list of objects using hibernate in spring data

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I need to store a list of objects in db using hibernate in spring data. Basically my need is to store the list in a single interaction with database.

for this, I am trying as below:

```
//a part of my code:
if(vacationAirTravellerLegInfoList.size() != 0) {   
            customVacationAirTravellerLegInfoRepository.save(vacationAirTravellerLegInfoList);
}
```

for this above part, 'customVacationAirTravellerLegInfoRepository' is object of custom repository I tried to implement as :

```
@Repository
public interface CustomVacationAirTravellerLegInfoRepository extends VacationAirTravellerLegInfoRepository, CrudRepository<VacationAirTravellerLegInfo, Integer> {
    List<VacationAirTravellerLegInfo> save(List<VacationAirTravellerLegInfo> airTravellerLegInfoList);

}
```

Implementation of this 'save(List)' method as :

```
public class CustomVacationAirTravellerLegInfoRepositoryImpl implements CustomVacationAirTravellerLegInfoRepository {

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<VacationAirTravellerLegInfo> save(List<VacationAirTravellerLegInfo> airTravellerLegInfoList) {

        try {
            //FIXME: exception on getting configuration object
            //sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory(); 
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            for (int i = 0; i < airTravellerLegInfoList.size(); i++) {
                VacationAirTravellerLegInfo vacationAirTravellerLegInfo = airTravellerLegInfoList.get(i);
                session.save(vacationAirTravellerLegInfo);
            }
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return airTravellerLegInfoList;
    }

    //other inherited methods from the inherited are not mentioned here..

}
```

when I am trying to execute `customVacationAirTravellerLegInfoRepository.save(vacationAirTravellerLegInfoList);` it is giving an exception as below :

```
{
    "timestamp": 1529303873662,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException",
    "message": "Invalid property 'id' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Could not find field for property during fallback access!",
    "path": "/api/server/vacation/save"
}
```

Anyone please suggest or correct me.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to cast your list element

```
VacationAirTravellerLegInfo vacationAirTravellerLegInfo =  (VacationAirTravellerLegInfo) airTravellerLegInfoList.get(i);
```

Comment: actually I am not getting control even reaching in save method

Comment: I made assumption from the given exception which says "spring-data  trying to find "id" property in ArrayList."